# "Print" text file to images with layout from command line

Tags: images, conversion, text

I have long journal files that I would like to view as images. I don't want to have to screencap my text editor. I am using LibreOffice to Export them to jpg, but I have to do everything ONE. STEP. AT. A. TIME. I am looking for some kind of command line layout program that would ostensibly look like this:

```
$ txt2jpg -i myfile.txt -o mynewfile --format=jpg --height=872 \
--width=600 --margins=40px --font=monospace
```

This would take `myfile.txt` as input and create a series of files named `mynewfile01.jpg, mynewfile02.jpg, ..., mynewfileNN.jpg` as output. The images would be 872 pixels tall, 600 wide, have a 40 pixel margin all around and use a font named monospace. Obviously, the actual program would differ in the particulars, but should be capable of taking one text file and outputting a series of jpgs (or pngs or bmps or whatever) as output with the ability to format the output image fontsize and so on.

Comment: How do you want the text presented? Do you want to do word wrapping or do you want to convert line by line? What about page breaks? Paragraphs? etc.

Comment: Word wrapping. There are no page breaks. Paragraphs are represented by two CRLFs (Unix style). There's not a lot of formatting. It's a text file.

Answer (score 4):

A traditional tool for printing simple text files is `enscript`. This produces PostScript output. You can convert this to an image in many ways. One that gives good results is `pdftopng` which needs the PostScript packaged into a pdf as input (eg with `ps2pdf`) and produces png image files. So, using `convert` from ImageMagick to convert to jpg you end up with:

```
enscript < myfile.txt --media A4 -f CourierBold10 -o - |
ps2pdf - >out.pdf
pdftopng -mono out.pdf out # creates files out-000001.png etc
for f in out-*.png
do convert -resize 600x872 "$f" "${f/png/jpg}"
   rm "$f"
done
rm out.pdf
```

Your output is in files `out*jpg`.

Comment: Does going via png confer any advantage over, say, piping the postscript straight to ghostscript with the jpeg/jfif driver? e.g. `enscript blah blah -o - myfile.txt | gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=myfile.jpg -`

Comment: @steeldriver Your suggestion sounds like a much better solution. please post as a full answer.

Comment: Actually I hadn't noticed the OP's scaling requirements - I'd have to think about that before attempting a full solution. Probably `gs` can do it ...

Comment: Why are you converting to JPEG? JPEG is bad at representing text: it's good for smooth color transitions (common in photos) and bad at sharp transitions. PNG is a lot better for an image of text.

Comment: Also, `convert` can take PDF as input, why are you using `pdftopng` first?

Comment: @Gilles I'm converting to jpeg as that's what the OP wanted. And I'm sadly not proficient enough with `convert` to know how to do multi-page stuff. Please, post more optimal solutions, as they clearly exist, and it's great to learn something new.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and creative responses. I am plowing through the man pages for enscript, ps2pdf, pdftopng, imagemagick, and gs to try to find a pipeline that doesn't get hung up.